# Login page resetting when change the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, authentication

I have `login_page_fragment` and `logged_page_fragment`. If the remember me `radio_button` is checked, username and password reading in shared_preferences but if I don't check it's not and when it's not checked when I navigate to another fragment and go back to logged profile it will navigate to login_page_fragment the question is how can I set the sessions temporary. I want to delete sessions when app closing.

I have if statement in login_page_fragment. It's looking for shared_preferences. And if there are a shared_preferences, navigates to logged_fragment.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Add a button to logout/quit your application and add a method to remove the shared_pref when you click on it. You can add an expiry time session on your shared_pref, and check it at the next opening session.

Comment: i have that button already. I want to store the userName and password temporary, not in the sharedpreferences. Is that possible?

Comment: You can store it in an Application object https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html . You can create a custom application class, get a singleton instance, and store login/password in member of this singleton